# DD data of drive to new drive within VM

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, dd, luks

I inherited a CentOS 7 vm with a messy disk system. Here's a breakdown:

The VM has 2 hard disks, and the OS has two LVs with luks-encryption on top. Output from `lsblk`:

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                             2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                                             8:0    0   40G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0  500M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                          8:2    0 29.5G  0 part
│ └─luks-05ef98b8-5161-4ca1-917e-8637bf8f0000 253:0    0 29.5G  0 crypt
│   ├─swap                                    253:1    0    3G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
│   └─root                                    253:2    0 76.5G  0 lvm   /
└─sda3                                          8:3    0   10G  0 part
  └─root                                      253:2    0 76.5G  0 lvm   /
sdb                                             8:16   0   40G  0 disk
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0   10G  0 part
│ └─root                                      253:2    0 76.5G  0 lvm   /
└─sdb2                                          8:18   0   30G  0 part
  └─root                                      253:2    0 76.5G  0 lvm   /
```

and lvm devices:

```
# ls /dev/mapper/
control
luks-05ef98b8-5161-4ca1-917e-8637bf8f0000
root
swap
```

**My goal just is to effectively remove the luks encryption.** It's the older LUKS1, so it's not able to decrypt while online. So far, I have been trying to copy all the data to a new drive, and boot to that instead:

- Add a new drive to the VM with enough space to hold everything (labeled `sdc`)
- copy everything to the drive:

  `# dd if=/dev/mapper/root of=/dev/sdc conv=noerror,sync`

This gets me a simple, unencrypted copy of my system, but I'm not sure how to get it booted from here. I can't just make a new `/boot` partition and copy the old one to it since all the lvm and luks-encryption configurations still live in grub for example. What is the easiest way to basically slide my OS out of the encryption? What kind of tools can make this easier?

Starting fresh with a new OS isn't an option for me.